# How to write test class with @Autowired variable for inherited class

Tags: spring, groovy, spring-boot, junit, spock

I have problem with writing test cases using SPOCK. Could anyone please help me?

I have classes & interfaces like below,

```
    //Helper class

    public class ObjClass{

        //Defining all property variables & corresponding getters & setters methods.

    }


    //Interface

    public interface B{ 

        //Declaring custom methods for Mongo repository.

        public int getId();
    }

    public interface A extends MongoRepository<ObjClass, Serializable>, B{ 

    //Defining some standard MongoRepository methods here

    }

    // Implementation Classes
    public class Aimpl implements B{ 

        //implementing all B interface methods

    }

    public class ctrlClass{

        @Autowired
        A aObj;

       public int getIdValue(){
         return aObj.getId();
       }

    }
```

And below is the corresponding SPOCK test cases:

```
class test extends Specification
{
    ctrlClass obj1
    A obj2   //interface class object


    def setup(){
        obj1 = new ctrlClass();

        obj2 = new Aimpl(); //Creating object for interface using impl class.

       obj1.aObj = obj2

    }

def "test"(){
    when:
    def a = obj2.getIdValue()
    then:
    //validating some conditions here with 'a' value
}

}
```

*Getting below error while executing above test case,*

**Cannot cast object Aimpl to class A.**

The same above scenario is working fine with Spring @Autowired. But not in Spock.

*

> Is there any alternate available for @Autowired in SPOCK? Please suggest me some solutions & your comments.

*

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is the ability of Spring to bind the interface with the related implementation.

If your interface has only one implementation and the single implementation has the annotation @Component with Spring's [component scan](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html) enabled, than Spring framework success to infer the relationship between the interface and its implementation.

In case the component scan is not enabled, then the bean should be explicitly defined in your spring configuration file (such as application-config.xml).

The casting of Aimpl and A cannot succeed because the inheritance classes/interface are different.

You should change the code like the following:

```
public class ctrlClass{

   @Autowired
   Aimpl aObj;

  public int getIdValue(){
    return aObj.getId();
  }
}
```

And in the test class make the following change:

```
A obj2   //interface class object
```

Should be changed to:

```
Aimpl obj2
```

Comment: If I change like this, 

`public class ctrlClass{

   @Autowired
   Aimpl aObj;

  public int getIdValue(){
    return aObj.getId();
  }
}`

I will not able to use interface A's method right?.

Note:
But in my current inheritance structure I can able to use both A's & B's interface methods.